# Deploy Outlook 2010 Addin setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-office, installation, add-in

I have developed an Outlook 2010 addin using Visual Studio 2010. When debugging/running from Visual Studio, everything works just fine. However, I am trying to make a setup so other users can simply install the addin. When running the setup on other computers, however, everything seems to work just fine, but the addin is not added to Microsoft Outlook.

By the way: even when running the setup on my computer (after having removed the addin that has been automatically added due to Visual Studio running), the addin is not added to MS Outlook. The addin project is referenced in the setup project that I build.

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried entering to outlook File -> Options -> Add-ins and check in the list if you app is registered and/or activated?

Comment: Then most likely its the way the installer works, are you using MSI or ClickOnceInstaller?

Comment: MSI. The only option, actually..? Or what other way is there to deploy a COM addin, for so far, the main part is simply the Office 2010 Addin project, nothing special, and a setup project to deploy it.

Comment: this helped a lot in my case.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/08/deploying-your-vsto-add-ins-to-all-users-saurabh-bhatia.aspx

Comment: No prob, please let me know how you got it fixed.

Comment: Try using ClickOnce Installer to, it is possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13937/discussion-between-arik-so-and-freeman)